# Backbone and MVC - event bubbling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, architecture, event-handling

I am trying to create a tree visualization widget using Backbone (and other libs) 
that is compliant with the MVC pattern.

I have a Node model and a Tree collection:

```
var Node = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name : 'NewNode',
        _id : null,
        parent_id: null,
        type : ''
    },
    idAttribute: '_id'
});

var Tree = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Node
});
```

and I have a view for each:

NodeView - renders a specific node's HTML

TreeView - going over each Node in the collection and appending them to the a div container.

```
var TreeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    ...

    render: function () {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addNewNode, this);
        return this;
    },
    addNewNode: function(nodeModel){
        var nodeView = new NodeView();
        nodeView.render();
        this.$el.find('.gnodes').append(nodeView.el);
        return this;
    },

    ...
```

I also have a module that acts as my controller (**Not Backbone's Router\Controller**)
and there I instantiate a TreeView with a Tree collection.

```
    var config = _.extend({}, defaults, options);
    var tree = new Tree();
    config.collection = tree;
    var treeView = new TreeView(config);
```

One of my view events is clicking on a node to edit its info - 
since its an event that happens on a node it made sense to me to have it on the NodeView.

```
var nodeView = SVGView.extend({
    ...

    events: {
        'click [data-action="editTitle"]': 'editNodeName'
    },
```

But now I have a problem - 
How do I bubble this event to the controller (so it could react to it)?

My controller doesn't have an instance of the NodeView - the TreeView is the place
that I create my NodeView (for rendering).

1. Should I bubble the event through the TreeView?
2. Or should I instantiate the NodeView in the Controller?

*Note: I tried to simplify things so I didn't reveal all of the views and the controller's code.*

Comment: when i talk about a controller i mean an MVC controller (a module that is in charge of all the logic between the model and the view). I do NOT mean Backbone's controller\router object.

Comment: why not if you try to pass `config` to `nodeView` and trace any of collection event. Or pass each model of the `config`'s collection to nodeView?

Comment: The `config` is not related to the issue - its something the user passes when creating the widget (an instance of the controller). I dont want to use Backbone's Router because i feel its not what I need here (i dont need to handle navigation between views).

Comment: but it seem you treat the `config` as the controller because you assign the collection to it

Comment: i pass an object to the TreeView which includes different parameters such as the collection. Look at it as 
`var treeView = new TreeView({ collection: tree });` instead.

Comment: then you should consider to pass the model to nested view

Comment: what do you mean? could you please give an example...?

Comment: I'd create the event handler in the controller and pass it to nodeView through TreeView. Then have nodeView pass the click event in editNodeName to the controller's event handler.

Comment: So, after thinking about this some more i figured i had a design flaw. What i ended up doing is adding another controller to handle (and instantiate) the NodeView. Now the 2 controllers can 'talk' to each other and they each listen to their own views.